# Why does my lighting setup only effect half of my object?

Tags: objects, lighting

thanks in advance for helping me out. I'm having issues lighting this scene because no matter what I do, only half of the ring is lit correctly. The right side is always a bit darker and the gems don't reflect their green color properly.

I couldn't figure out why half of this ring was lit even when I placed a point light directly above the ring. I overexposed it here so it's clearer.

Any tips and solutions are greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: hello, hard to say without the file, maybe a light is hidden for preview but enabled for render, or maybe it's due to your HDRI?

Comment: Hi what's the best way to share a file here?

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload and share the link